# cpu usage 100% without any processes, and returns to normal in high performance mode in hp dv4

Tags: cpu-usage

I am having a hp pavilion dv4 laptop. recently I replaced my battery with a brand new one. after that my laptop cpu usage shows 100% without any processes running. This continues even after i removed the battery and works on AC power. When I switched to high performance mode, the problem doesn't occurs. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like either the battery software needs updated or you have allot of background processes running

press ctrl+alt+delete and check the process and the services tabs carful though deleting or ending the wrong files could crash the system stay away from *32 items on the lists